# Adding swap takes 90 seconds?

Tags: boot, swap

Adding SWAP takes 90 seconds on my Lubuntu 14.04 machine. I dont know why this happens, it makes my computer boot very slowly. How can I resolve this? My RAM is 2 GB, HD is 250 GB with only one partition.

```
      [    4.352025] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
      [    5.718270] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
    **[   94.134265] Adding 2094076k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2094076k FS**
      [   96.988453] init: bootchart main process (274) terminated with status 127
```

FSTAB

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ca1e2698-8701-4d53-84f0-e0e7e1c5d4ee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=12aecaa8-85e8-4bc2-a069-9ba96bbe0b40 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Bootchart (from yesterday)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXnGa.png

Sudo blkid output

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="ca1e2698-8701-4d53-84f0-e0e7e1c5d4ee" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="12aecaa8-85e8-4bc2-a069-9ba96bbe0b40" TYPE="swap"
```

CHeck bootchart guys. Boot takes 130 secs. Custom kernel? its lubuntu downloaded from the official site.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the contents of `/etc/fstab` into your question so we can see what's going on exactly? (Please help us help you!) Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: @Fabby added the fstab file content you asked for.

Comment: Looks OK...  Could you also add the output of `sudo blkid` and do a `sudo apt-get install bootchart` and post a link to the output from the last `png` from `/var/log/bootchart/`?  (Unfortunately, that needs a reboot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it usual Ubuntu 14.04.2 to take a long time at "random: nonblocking pool is initialized" step during boot process?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672121/is-it-usual-ubuntu-14-04-2-to-take-a-long-time-at-random-nonblocking-pool-is-i)

Comment: @Fabby added the content you asked for.

Comment: @E.F. Nijboer Doubt its  the same error. His delay was 10 seconds mine is a minute and a half. Nonetheless i tried what those guys suggested in that question and it dint do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making sense of Time in dmesg](http://askubuntu.com/questions/749419/making-sense-of-time-in-dmesg)

Comment: @telminatol: Probing seems very likely. The difference in the length of the delay can be because of a different time-out or reaction of the hardware. Have you tried disabling bluetooth? (especially when you don't have any bluetooth device(s) ).

Comment: @Fabby the kernel does look like http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic-lts-wily

Comment: disabled  bluetooth fully. Didn't improve anything.

Comment: Close vote retracted...

Comment: Did it solved ?